# Issues encountered with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Subjects]
    @Subj_ID nvarchar(9)
AS
    DECLARE @First3Digits nvarchar(3);
    DECLARE @Result int;
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)

    -- Fetching the fiest 3 digits of the subject
    SET @First3Digits = SUBSTRING(@Subj_ID,1,3);

    -- Check if view is present or not
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE Name = @First3Digits)
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql = 'select @Result = case when exists (select 1 from dbo.' + quotename(@First3Digits) + ' where SubjectName = ''' + @Subj_ID + ''') then 1 else 0 end';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Subj_ID nvarchar(9), @Result bit out', @Subj_ID = @Subj_ID, @Result = @Result out; 
        -- checking if the subject is present in the view    
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Create a view as view doesn't exist
        SET @Sql = 'create view ' + @First3Digits 
                    + ' as 
    (select SubjectName from dbo.Subjects where SubjectName like '+@First3Digits+'%'+');';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, N'@First3Digits nvarchar(3)', @First3Digits= @First3Digits;
        SET @Result = 0;
    END

    RETURN @Result
GO
```

This is the code for executing the stored procedure:

```
EXEC [dbo].[Create_Subjects] '1234567890'
```

Error encountered:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: That is the syntax for create view statement

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near '%'.

Comment: If your view name doesn't conform to regular identifier naming rules (e.g. it starts with a number), you also must enclose the name in double quotes or square brackets. Use `QUOTENAME` like you did earlier in the proc: `SET @Sql = 'create view ' + QUOTENAME(@First3Digits)`

Comment: You are also missing apostrophes when you add @First3Digits in your create view.  You did it correctly in the SELECT block, but not the CREATE VIEW block.

Comment: Issue Encountered: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near '%'.

Comment: Rather than creating a view for each parameter look at inline table valued functions

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your SQL. But firstly the way to debug them is to print the SQL without executing it, then its normal SQL and you can easily identify what is wrong with it.

1. No brackets are allowed around the SQL making up the view.
2. You have to quote your strings as per normal, which means doubling up the quotes in the dynamic string.
3. Use `quotename` again as suggested in the comments.
4. There is no need to pass the parameter `@First3Digits` into `sp_executesql` because by that point you've used its value - which you have to do given you are creating a view.

```
    set @Sql = 'create view dbo.' + quotename(@First3Digits)
        + ' as'
        + ' select SubjectName'
        + ' from dbo.Subjects'
        + ' where SubjectName like ''' + @First3Digits + ''' + ''%'';';

    -- This is how you debug dynamic SQL
    print(@Sql);

    execute sp_executesql @Sql;
```

Note: As I mentioned in your previous question, with the information provided, this seems to be a really bad design. There is almost certainly a better way to solve your bigger picture problem. As commented by Martin Smith an [Inline Table Valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might be worth investigating.

Comment: This is a SQL injection attack vector, though. That may be an inherent problem if making a view, but it is still crucial to be aware of.

Comment: @MarcGravell how would you fix it? You can't create a view that uses a parameter... so I guess it just needs escaping somehow?

Comment: @DaleK I revised my words a bit; since a view is involved (reading it a second time), that is more problematic. I'd probably just avoid this scenario with a very large barge pole. Like "social distancing" but for RDBMS.

Comment: Yeah, I added note to that effect on OP's first question. But didn't receive any further details to be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Indeed, but its all dependent on the rest of the OP's system - one assumes its currently setup to query a view of a particular name.

Comment: Also do you recon you can fit enough SQL into a `nvarchar(3)` for an injection attack? :)